# Is it advisable to develop web-parts using VB.net?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, asp.net

Hope everyone is doing well.

our public facing website has around 50 parts and among those 50,23 webparts are developed on

> VB.net and remaining on C#.net,

Sometimes performance of the website is not getting as expecting, so Our managers have got the information from one of the sharepoint consultant that we should not use VB.net to develop webparts and we should change them all to c#.net.

My question is it neccessary?
Website gets daily more than 2lakhs hits and it takes 2.seconds to 4seconds to load the complete website.

If it's neccessary to move vb.net to c#.net
is there any automatic process where we can change the

> VB.net code to C#.net?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will say it is not necessary to change web part from VB.Net to c#. Rather try to find which process is taking long time to execute, how many calls are going in that, what is the size of js, css load in that web part.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response,

May I please know is there any method to find which webpart taking how much time to complete it's process??

Comment: Have you write javascript code or code behind code in webpart?

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET as long as C# both compiled to intermediate language (called IL) code, which later gets executed by .NET runtime. Similar functions written in VB.NET and in C# produce the same IL code, that means that in terms of performance it's absolutely useless to change code from VB.NET to C#.

What you actually need is to try to find potential "bottlenecks" in web parts by using different approaches.
Let me try to list this common approaches:

- Use your browser's developer tools to analyze how long does it take to load a page. The simplest and handy tool is Chrome's Network tab. From this analysis you will have a idea, if it your javascript loads too long, or if it's server side code. Info - [Measure Resource Loading Times](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading)
- Enable SharePoint developer dashboard to analyze all requests with timings which occurs on the server when you page is loading. Info - [Using the SharePoint 2013 Developer Dashboard](https://www.petri.com/sharepoint-2013-developer-dashboard-introduction)
- Analyze your web parts code and data. If there are lists with many items and your code is iterating this items, that's potential bottleneck. May be you have an issues with disposing, that's also potential bottleneck (when memory consumption is increasing)
- Finally you can use some advanced tools like sampling application profiling using Visual Studio command-line tools. More info - [Collecting Application Statistics for ASP.NET Web Applications Using the Profiler Sampling Method from the Command Line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255446.aspx)